# How to let users make a backup of their data within a webapplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a ASP.NET web-application with a MySQL database behind.
My users wants to make a backup of their data when clicking on a button.
How should I do that?

I was thinking of using mysqldump to create a database and let the user download this file.
But is that the easiest way? And what about performance ? I have currently 250 users working an the webapplication at the same time. So when they all press the backup button ... I don't want to let my server hanging while creating the backup.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thx

Comment: I'd use a proprietary XML format for these backups.  Your site would be able to generate them, as well as parse them if users wanted to restore the data.

Comment: IMO, this should be done off peak hours. Configure a scheduler to perform backups and notify via. downloadable links, this way multiple users can download single file. And again it depends on request frequency to decide upon this.

Comment: What does their data consist of? Database tables? How many? How complex are the relationships? Are the files in the file system?

Comment: the backup contains the contents of the database tables appr. 60. there are not many relationships in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this tool: **MySqlBackup.NET**, which is an alternative to MySqlDump. 
Official Site & Documentation > http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/

**Backup & Download a MySQL Database**

```
void Backup()
{
    string connection = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string fileOnDisk = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyDumpFile.sql");
    // Example Result: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyDumpFile.sql
    string fileOnWeb = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
                       + "/MyDumpFile.sql";
    // Example Result: http://www.mywebsite.com/MyDumpFile.sql

    // Backup MySQL Database
    MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(connection);
    mb.ExportInfo.FileName = fileOnDisk;
    mb.Export();

    // Download the file
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyDumpFile.sql");
    Response.TransmitFile(fileOnDisk);
    Response.End();
}
```

**Restore a MySQL Database**

```
void Restore()
{
    string connection = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
    string fileOnDisk = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MyDumpFile.sql");
    string fileOnWeb = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
                       + "/MyDumpFile.sql";
    // Upload the file
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileOnDisk);

        MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(connection);
        mb.ImportInfo.FileName = fileOnDisk;
        mb.Import();
        Response.Write("Import Successfully");
    }
}
```

From the above example, **MySqlBackup.NET** will create a file name **MyDumpFile.sql** (The exported MySQL database).
You can cache the file for 5 or 10 minutes. If any user wants to get the exported MySQL Backup File within 5 or 10 minutes from time of creation, the cache file will be transmitted for his/her to download. If more than 5 or 10 minutes, new cache file will be generated again.
I am one of the author of this tool.